# How to check if switch is true or not to hide the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

I have some problem when I check the function validation, I need when checking all the cassis is true hide the parent div * errors message *

[image: checkin all the rules]

```
var error_pass = false;

  $('#pass').focusout(function(){
        check_pass();
        error_pass = false;
        if(error_pass !== true){
            console.log('its showing!');
        }else{
            $('.test').fadeOut('522');
        }
    });


   function check_pass() {
        var fpass= $('#pass').val();
        switch(error_pass = true){
            case(fpass.length < 6 ? $('#pass-error-message3').css('color','red'):$('#pass-error-message3').css('color','green') ):
              $('#pass-error-message3').show();
            case(fpass.search(/(?=.[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/) == -1 ? $('#pass-error-message4').css('color','red') : $('#pass-error-message4').css('color','green')):
                $('#pass-error-message4').show();
            case(fpass.search(/\d/) == -1 ? $('#pass-error-message2').css('color','red'):$('#pass-error-message2').css('color','green')):
                $('#pass-error-message2').show();
            default:break;
        }
  }
```

Comment: That's not how you use a switch, just use if statements

Comment: @Luca yeah I know but when I use if statements I need to put the var error_pass in all the else statements, and then to check the first if condition they will hide the parent Errors, without check another statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if else statements like this

```
function validation() {
  var error = false;
  if (fpass.length < 6) {
    error = true;
    $('#pass-error-message3').css('color', 'red').show();
  } else {
    $('#pass-error-message3').css('color', 'green');
  }
  if (fpass.search(/(?=.[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/) == -1) {
    error = true;
    $('#pass-error-message4').css('color', 'red').show();
  } else {
    $('#pass-error-message4').css('color', 'green')
  }

  if(fpass.search(/\d/) == -1){
    error = true;
    $('#pass-error-message2').css('color','red').show();
  }else{
    $('#pass-error-message2').css('color','green');
  }

  if(error === false){
    hideParentDiv(); // Here hide the div
  }

}
```

Much cleaner approach

Comment: Oh man, big thanks, but why you declare the var inside the function?

Comment: @AnasTe i assume that this function is called again and again on every key stroke, then this variable is always needed anyways , then no need to put it in global scope